# Selectable index of List or Array

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to make a list or array with a property like SelectedIndex or SelectedValue so could be cycled with a method, it is probably counterproductive to use in this case but it could be handy in a state based application.
This can be done easily like:

```
string[] asFoods = new string[] {"Pizza", "Donut", "Burgers"};
int iSelected = 0;

public void cycleFood()
{
    iSelected = (iSelected < 2) ? iSelected + 1 : 0;
}
```

Also I can add the property to the String or the List<> class, but I'm looking for something integrated already in C#.

Comment: There's not a built-in type that does that.  There are some UI controls that have a `SelectedIndex` property but they are not designed for use outside of a visual context.

Comment: @DStanley yeah, I thought about using UI controls but it's just not wise outside a visual context like you said. Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually care about the index of the selected value, or do you want the actual value selected?

Comment: @aaron I planned to use it in a large array of company names, and cycle it when the user chooses one or a _next_ button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything straight out of the box that does this, so I would recommend creating what is essentially a wrapper class for List.

You would have an object class that contains a List of names, your other assorted information (index numbers, etc), and then methods (such as your cycling). I would imagine that you will find a need for other methods as well, such as loading name information from a database.

Comment: Indeed. It seems this is the most feasible way. Thank you.